# App Share Extension failed to use backgroundSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, nsurlsession

When I test my App Share Extension, I get stuck with this problem:

First, I configured my app and the share extension's share groups like this:
[image]

Then, I tried to use my shared user defaults, and it worked fine, like this:
[image]

So, I tried to do the similar thing to configure the background session, like this:
[image]

However, I got this crashed.
[image]

I've do a lot of work on this, but still can't figure it out. I think I've made the data sharing between the container app and the extension. However it seems that I did something wrong. I have no idea now. Sincerely hope someone could help me with this. Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you Please explain your problem what exactly you are trying to do with in AFnetworking?

Comment: @BhupatBheda I just want to use AFNetworking to upload images with background session configuration within my app share extension. That's all. But It seems that unless I use background session configuration to upload, I t goes wrong.

Comment: please comment the line config.sharedContainerIdentifer

Comment: @BhupatBheda If I do not use background session configuration, images uploading is fine. Or If I do use background session configuration, but  do not upload any images, it also works!  However, if both, request will fail! I learn that it is caused by the data sharing between the container app and the extension and I've made the configuration. Thus, it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Please post you code instead of image so i could go through ?

Comment: @BhupatBheda Would please tell me why I should comment the line? The official Document says that if you want use a background session configuration, you must set that property.

Comment: @BhupatBheda Ok, wait a minute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143257/discussion-between-bhupat-bheda-and-neal-marlin).